# Is "I don't like girls smoking" a correct sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, usage, sentence-structure, gerunds, reduced-relative-clauses

I have two questions:

**1.** To express the same meaning as

> "I don't like girls who smoke."

can I say

> "I don't like girls smoking."?

It sounds kind of odd to me but I think it is not wrong.

**2.** To express the same meaning as

> "She is a girl who smokes."

can I say

> "She is a girl smoking."?

This one sounds somewhat odd to me too.

**UPDATE:** In some kinds of sentences, instead of pronouns like "who", "which" and "that", we can use the continuous form. So what I am asking is: Instead of using the version with "who", can I just use the continuous form in those sentences I gave.

- An example of what I mean:
  You can say **"I love her face smiling at me every morning"** instead of **"I love her face that (which) smiles at me every morning"**
- Another example:
  Let's say a friend of yours is at your apartment, and you are talking about a bar with him. In that context, you can say **"I like the girl singing at that bar."** for meaning **"I like the girl who sings at that bar."** as far as I know.

Comment: Please be clear: is it the girls you dislike or their smoking? Perhaps "I don't like it when girls smoke". Secondly "the girl smokes", "the girl is smoking", "she is a smoker". "I don't like girls who smoke." means you don't like those girls at all. "I don't like girls smoking." either means you don't like girls when they smoke, or you don't approve of their habit.

Comment: *A right sentence* is unnatural.  We'd usually say *a correct sentence*.  When we use *right* before a noun (in the 'correct' meaning), it's usually definite; we're usually picking out the one correct choice or answer in a given context, so we say things like *the right answer* (not *a right answer*).

Comment: @snailboat I thought we could use "right" instead of "correct". Maybe it is not wrong, but unnatural.

Comment: @WeatherVane When you say "There is a woman taking care of his children when he is not at home", it means "...a woman who takes care of..." This is why I am asking this question.

Comment: I don't understand the relevance of that comment. If it relevant, please edit the question to make it more clear what you are asking. I pointed out an ambiguity in your question, sorry you didn't take it.

Comment: If you want to use "smiling" as an adjective then you can say "*I love [seeing] her* ***smiling face*** *in the morning*" OR *"I love waking up to her* ***smiling face***"*

Comment: "I don't like girls who smokes, too". actually, I don't like people smoke...

Answer (score 2):

1) "I don't like girls smoking." seems like "I don't like it when girls smoke." which is slightly different.

Instead, you could say "I don't like smokers", if it's enough in the context.

2) First of all, when talking about "a girl" you want to use "she" as the pronoun, instead of "he".

Again, "She is a smoker." works just fine, it could also be "She smokes."

Verbs in the continous form ("-ing") are usually used to describe a particular moment, so "she is smoking" = right now vs. "she smokes" = she is a smoker

(edit: unless you mean smoking as an adjective in which case it should go in front of the noun "she is a smoking girl" but then it'd just mean "hot"https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=smokin)

Comment: Also. You are wrong by the way. You can use verbs in the continuous form in the sentences like "There is a guy looking at me all the time in the class". The meaning is "There is a guy who looks at me all the time in the class" here.

Comment: Oh, yes, that's why I wrote "usually", the continous form indicates annoyment, but yeah, you're right. I meant in the context of your question :)

Comment: I am sorry but it doesn't have anything to do with being annoyed as far as I know. It is just an alternative to "who". For example you can say "The music playing at that bar is so nice" for meaning "The music that plays at that bar is so nice". It doesn't have anything to do with being annoyed.

Comment: Oh, okay, yes, then "playing" becomes an adjective (I think :P), what I mean is "Use present continuous to talk about habits that are annoying and bother us. ("always" "constantly," "continuously," and "continually")." - https://www.learn-english-have-fun.com/present-simple-and-present-continuous.html

Comment: @FireandIce - There is a big difference between the example in your first comment and the example in Pantera's answer. I think most native speakers would interpret "There is a guy looking at me in class" to mean that there is someone looking at that person right now. You clarified by adding "all the time" – _"There is a guy looking at me all the time in the class"_ – which suggests ongoing behavior. Similarly, I would think "She is a girl smoking," means she is smoking right now, not someone who smokes as a habit, as "She is a girl who smokes" (or "She is a smoker") would mean.

Comment: @J.R. Thanks. Without using "all the time", it can have two meanings as far as I know.

Comment: Let's say I am at home at night, and talking to my brother. In that context, would "There is a guy staring at me in the class" mean that that guy is straring at me at the moment in the class? :) I think no. Wouldn't it mean "There is a guy who stares at me in the class"?

Comment: @FireandIce Did you notice how J.R. changed your "in the class" example to "in class"?  It sounds much better that way.

Comment: @snailboat "There is a guy staring at me in class" can have two meanings, right? It can mean either *"There is a guy who is staring at me in class"* or *"There is a guy who stares at me in class"*. Am I right?

Answer (score -1):

> 1. ***She is smoking***
>       <sub>We can drop the redundant “a girl” from the original phrase.</sub>

Without greater context this could mean:

(i) She is smoking an illegal substance at this moment.
(ii) She is literally burning at this moment = smoke is being emitted from her
(iii) She is smoking hot (slang) = she is sexually attractive

Therefore, the following sentence is grammatically correct, but it sounds incomplete.

> *I don't like girls smoking*

The verb "[**smoke**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/smoke)" is both intransitive and transitive

> **2.** (no object) Inhale and exhale the smoke of tobacco or a drug.
>
> - *‘Janine was sitting at the kitchen table smoking’*
> - (with **object**) *‘he smoked **forty cigarettes** a day’*

By adding an object or a prepositional phrase, the OP's sentence will sound more idiomatic and the risk of being misunderstood will be reduced.

> *I don't like girls smoking **cigarettes**/**weed**/**cigars*** (etc.)
>   *I don't like girls smoking* ***in bars***

In the following, the speaker is talking about a specific  girl or  group of people by using the present continuous tense

> *I like* ***the*** *girl* [who is] ***singing*** *at that bar* (at this moment)
>   *I like* ***the*** *girls* [who are] ***singing*** *at that bar* (at this moment)

To express a general preference or truth, it's best to use the simple present, ergo

> I like a girl who **sings**
>   I like girls who **sing**

OR

> I like female/girl **singers**

Likewise, to express the idea of generally disliking any girl who smokes, the noun should be plural and the tense should be the present simple

> I don't like girls who smoke
>   I don't like [female] **smokers**

Comment: Would be nice to know what I got wrong. Is it just a bad answer? Let me know, thanks.

Comment: Can I say "A girl smoking cigarettes is a turnoff" for meaning "A girl who smokes cigarettes is a turnoff"? I think so.

Comment: @FireandIce Yeah that sounds ok, but you also added the object (cigarettes) It's more natural to say "Girls who smoke are a real turnoff" OR "Women smokers turn me off"

Comment: Thank you. Can I say "She is a girl smoking cigarettes" and "She is a girl smoking in her house" for meaning "She is a girl who smokes cigarettes" and "She is a girl who smokes in her house"?

Comment: Why do you need to say that "she" is a girl? It's not wrong but it seems a bit unnecessary. Just say "*That's a girl smoking in her home*" OR "*She is someone who likes smoking/smokes*". By the way, it's not "for meaning" but "to mean". use the infinite to talk about the purpose or  scope of something.

Comment: As far as I know we can use "for" as well. This is my first time hearing this.

Comment: Thanks. It seems you are right: http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv284.shtml  I wonder if the rule is the same in American English. Where are you from?

Comment: By the way I didn't completely get if you mean those last two sentences I gave a half hour ago are correct or not. You say that I can use those sentences, but it is better if I say "someone (somebody)" instead of "a girl" right? I mean I can say *"She is a girl (someone) smoking cigarettes"* to mean *"She is a girl (someone) who smokes cigarettes"*  or I can say *"She is a girl (someone) smoking in her house"* for meaning *"She is a girl (someone) who smokes in her house"* right?

Comment: @FireandIce   Yes, that's right. Instead of saying "a girl", you can also use "someone". "A girl who smokes" will suggest either a teenager or a very young woman. Someone in her 30s won't normally be called "a girl".